# SPRING BOOT: INSERTAR REGISTRO MANY TO MANY CON COLUMNAS EXTRAS

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Buenos dias llevo un par de días desesperado. Estoy realizando mi TFG y me esta surgiendo un problema, el cuál creo que comprendo pero no se como solucionarlo. Mi proyecto consiste en un polideportivo con muchas actividades y la posibilidad de alquilar pistas o campos. Estoy realizando el apartado donde alquilo y a la hora de introducirlo en la base de datos(mysql) me surge un problema, el error por lo que he estado investigando proviene de hibernate pero como he dicho no se como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`Sat May 22 15:00:40 CEST 2021 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.Alquila#com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.AlquilaPK@3e1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.Alquila#com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.AlquilaPK@3e1] org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.Alquila#com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.AlquilaPK@3e1]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.Alquila#com.springboot.tfg.app.models.entity.AlquilaPK@3e1] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:400) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy758.save(Unknown Source) at com.springboot.tfg.app.models.service.AlquilaServiceImpl.insertarAlquila(AlquilaServiceImpl.java:51) at com.springboot.tfg.app.controllers.ClienteController.alquilarPista(ClienteController.java:409) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)`

**Cliente.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable{
    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4836439129317129251L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String nombre;

@NotBlank
private String apellidos;

@Min(111111111)
@Max(999999999)
private int telefono;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date fecha_nac;

@NotBlank
@Email
private String email;

@NotBlank
private String password;

private String foto;

@JoinTable(
        name = "se_apunta",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente_aux", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="id_deporte_aux", nullable = false)
    )
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Deporte> deportes;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "clienteAlquila", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Alquila> alquila;

public void addDeporte(Deporte deporte){
    
    if(this.deportes == null){
        this.deportes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    this.deportes.add(deporte);
}

public void addAlquila(Alquila alquila){
    
    if(this.alquila == null){
        this.alquila = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    this.alquila.add(alquila);
}

public Cliente(){
    
}   

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public int getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public Date getFecha_nac() {
    return fecha_nac;
}

public void setFecha_nac(Date fecha_nac) {
    this.fecha_nac = fecha_nac;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFoto() {
    return foto;
}

public void setFoto(String foto) {
    this.foto = foto;
}

public List<Deporte> getDeportes() {
    return deportes;
}

public void setListaDeportes(List<Deporte> listaDeportes) {
    this.deportes = listaDeportes;
}

public List<Alquila> getAlquila() {
    return alquila;
}

public void setAlquila(List<Alquila> alquila) {
    this.alquila = alquila;
}
```

}´

**Pistas.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="pistas")
public class Pistas {   

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id_pista;

private String tipo;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pista", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Alquila> alquila = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id_pista;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id_pista = id;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String nombre) {
    this.tipo = nombre;
}
```

}

**Alquila.class** ENTITY N:N

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alquila")
public class Alquila {

@EmbeddedId
private AlquilaPK id = new AlquilaPK();

private String hora_inicio;

private String hora_final;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date fecha;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId("id_cliente")
@JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente_aux")
private Cliente clienteAlquila;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapsId("id_pista")
@JoinColumn(name = "id_pista_aux")
private Pistas pista;

public Alquila(String hora_inicio, String hora_final, Date fecha, Cliente clienteAlquila, Pistas pista) {
    this.hora_inicio = hora_inicio;
    this.hora_final = hora_final;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.clienteAlquila = clienteAlquila;
    this.pista = pista;
}

public Alquila() {}

public AlquilaPK getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(AlquilaPK id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getHora_inicio() {
    return hora_inicio;
}

public void setHora_inicio(String hora_inicio) {
    this.hora_inicio = hora_inicio;
}

public String getHora_final() {
    return hora_final;
}

public void setHora_final(String hora_final) {
    this.hora_final = hora_final;
}

public Date getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public Cliente getClienteAlquila() {
    return clienteAlquila;
}

public void setClienteAlquila(Cliente clienteAlquila) {
    this.clienteAlquila = clienteAlquila;
}

public Pistas getPista() {
    return pista;
}

public void setPista(Pistas pista) {
    this.pista = pista;
}
```

}

**AlquilaPK.class**

```
@Embeddable
public class AlquilaPK implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "id_cliente_aux")
public Long id_cliente;

@Column(name = "id_pista_aux")
public Long id_pista;

public AlquilaPK(Long id_cliente, Long id_pista) {
    this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
    this.id_pista = id_pista;
}

public AlquilaPK() {}

public Long getId_cliente() {
    return id_cliente;
}

public void setId_cliente(Long id_cliente) {
    this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
}

public Long getId_pista() {
    return id_pista;
}

public void setId_pista(Long id_pista) {
    this.id_pista = id_pista;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    AlquilaPK that = (AlquilaPK) o;
    return Objects.equals(id_cliente, that.id_cliente) &&
           Objects.equals(id_pista, that.id_pista);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id_cliente, id_pista);
}
}
```

**AlquilaDAO.class**

```
public interface IAlquilaDAO extends CrudRepository<Alquila, Long>{

    public List<Alquila> findAll();
}
```

**AlquilaService.class**

```
public interface IAlquilaService {

    public List<Alquila> findAll();

    public void insertarAlquila(Alquila alquila);
}
```

**AlquilaImpl.class**

```
@Service
public class AlquilaServiceImpl implements IAlquilaService{

@Autowired
private IAlquilaDAO alquilaDao;

@Override
public List<Alquila> findAll() {
    
    List<Alquila> listaAlquila = alquilaDao.findAll();
    
    return listaAlquila;
}

@Override
public void insertarAlquila(Alquila alquila) {      
    alquilaDao.save(alquila);
}

}
```

**Metodo del controlador**

```
@ModelAttribute("cliente")
  public Cliente usuario() {
    
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    
    Cliente cliente = null;
    
    if(auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        cliente = clienteDao.findByEmail(auth.getName());
    }
    
    return cliente;
  }

@PostMapping("/alquilado")
public String alquilarPista(@Valid Tarjeta tarjeta, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(name = 
"tipo") String nombre, Model model, RedirectAttributes flash) {
                    
    Pistas pista = pistasService.findByTipo(nombre);
            
    Alquila alquila = new Alquila(tarjeta.getHora(), horaFinal, tarjeta.getFecha(), usuario(), 
pista);
    alquilaService.insertarAlquila(alquila);
    
    flash.addAttribute("success", "Has alquilado el campo de futbol");
    
    return "redirect:/";
```

Si leemos el error me dice que que tengo dos objetos con iguales con diferentes valores, me imagino que como el usuario ha iniciado sesión y estoy metiendo su objeto (mediante el modelAttribute)dentro del objeto alquila como que hace una copia. No entiendo muy bien que hago mal.

Un detalle, he intentado meter un registro en la base de datos mediante phpmyAdmin y a la hora de recogerlo con el objeto cliente y el get de alquila, me detecta un regsitro nuevo pero con lo mismos valores del ultimo registro.

Seria de gran ayuda ya que me quedan pocos días para la entrega. Muchas gracias por leerme.

Comment: Primero que nada si estas usando @EmbeddedId debes de tener el id en la clase incrustada es decir, en AlquilaPK, lo otro es que puede que el hashcode te este molestando ya que puede repetirse el cliente con la pista, quita la sobreescritura del hascode

Comment: Buenas no sé a que te refieres con tener la id en la clase incrustada. He intentado lo que dices del hasCode y nada me sigue saliendo el mismo error. ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: No sé muy bien por que pero me deja insertar un registro por cada cliente, pero un cliente no puede hacer más de uno. Lo que hace es duplicarme el primer registro de ese cliente. Todo esto me refiero con el phpMyAdmin